# How can i remotely connect ODBC using Java in Windows XP?

Tags: java, odbc

My remote database is Mysql database and i want to retreive some records and put into the
 Microsoft Access database which is a localhost database

and i want to also create DSN for remote database

please help me

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: How can i create DSN for remote database?

Comment: Why do you need to talk to MySQL using ODBC? Why not JDBC to MySQL, and JDBC-ODBC bridge to Access?

Comment: That's probably the answer he was looking for, skaffman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just got a similar set up working in MATLAB which uses java to connect to MySQL and Access databases.
I created a java class with the following method

```
/**
 * Open a connection to a MySQL database
 * @param userName      registered user on the MySQL database.
 * @param userPassword  MySQL database password for the named user.
 * @param databaseUrl   database name eg. 'jdbc:mysql://glnd2818898.network.net/matlab'
 */
 public void openMySQLConnection(String userName, String userPassword, String databaseUrl){
    try {
        Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection (databaseUrl, userName, userPassword);

    }catch (SQLException e) {System.err.println ("Cannot connect to database server");}
 }
```

This runs over an internal network, so as per the  comments defining the databaseUrl glnd2818898.network.net is the MySQL server and it connects to the database 'matlab'

The Access interface is similar

```
    private static final String accessDBURLPrefix = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=";
    private static final String accessDBURLSuffix = ";READONLY=true}";

    /**
     * Open a connection to a Access database
     * @param userName      registered user on the Access database.
     * @param userPassword  Access database password for the named user.
     * @param databaseUrl   database name eg. 'pathname/accessName.mdb'
     */
public void openConnAccess(String userName, String userPassword, String databaseUrl){
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                    String dbUrl = accessDBURLPrefix + databaseUrl + accessDBURLSuffix;
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl, userName, userPassword);
    }catch (SQLException e) {System.err.println ("Cannot connect to database server  :" + e.getMessage());}
}
```

It's probably not the neatest java coding as it was my first attempt from a MATLAB users point of view, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [JDBC ODBC Bridge](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) to connect to your ODBC database.