# communicate MATLAB SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, matlab

Is there a way to communicate these Platforms effieciently?
I'm saying, something like exporting (SQL Server)and load (Matlab) but in an efficient way?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Database Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/database/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found [adodb_tools](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29615-adodbtools) on File Exchange to work the best so far. It's much faster than the database toolbox or any prior wrapping solutions.

Doesn't require additional toolboxes but in all likelihood will require you're on Windows for the ADO OLEDB ActiveX support.

Answer (score 1):

Use MATLAB's capability to run Java code in order to access any database that provides a JDBC driver. If you mind using Java, buy the [Database Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/database/) as mentioned by @b3.

Comment: I've always found it easier (and cheaper) to write a fairly simple wrapper class around the JDBC calls, so you only have to deal with all of that complexity once.  The key is if you're deploying your code in multiple places, a robust solution for keeping track of the required jar file requires some careful thought.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned use Java and the JDBC driver for your chosen database.

If you look through Stackoverflow there are a few posting about connecting MATLAB and MySQL.

[MySQL and Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477476/mysql-and-matlab/2478013#2478013)

and

[How can i remotely connect ODBC using Java in Windows XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138530/how-can-i-remotely-connect-odbc-using-java-in-windows-xp/2139141#2139141)

These solutions should work with a little tweaking for your database driver.