# adodb_tools MATLAB

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, matlab

Have you comunicated `SQL Server` and `MATLAB` using `adodb_tools`?

Do you have a simple example of loading a SQL result or a table into `MATLAB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a full tutorial linked from adodb_tools.
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/29615/1/content/html/adodb_tutorial_script.html

I've not used it myself because as I mentioned in your previous question
[communicate MATLAB SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111199/communicate-matlab-sql-server)
I use the Java ODBC driver method for database connections.

The tutorial looks fairly comprehensive so I'd give it a try and if you get stuck on a particular bit then ask a specific question.